# Несколько одинаковых js-скриптов echarts на одной странице

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap4, queryselector

У меня есть скрипт из библиотеки echarts, с помощью которого я строю диаграммы на своей html-странице. Я пытаюсь вызвать его несколько раз на одной странице в разных вкладках блока nav-tabs.
Сам скрипт, с помощью которого я строю диаграммы, такой:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
echarts.init(document.querySelector("#trafficChart1")).setOption({
tooltip: {
    //tooltip settings
},
legend: {
    //legend settings
},
series:[{
    //diagramm settings
data: [
   {value: 50,  name: 'Region_100'},
   {value: 150, name: 'Region_200'},
   {value: 250, name: 'Region_300'}
      ]
}]
});
});
```

Я попробовал назначить разным вкладкам в блоке nav-tabs разные id (соответственно, trafficChart1, trafficChart2, trafficChart3):

```
<div id="trafficChart1" style="min-height: 300px;" class="echart"></div>   
<script> 
    //здесь вышеприведенный код
</script>
```

Соответственно, вызывая вышеприведенный js-код повторно, я меняю только значение querySelector на #trafficChart2 и #trafficChart3 и данные для самой диаграммы.
По итогу мне нужно, чтобы во всех трех вкладках блока nav-tabs появились диаграммы, а она появляется только на первой вкладке, а на других вкладках ничего нет.
[image: первая вкладка - диаграмма отрисовалась]
На второй и третьей вкладках диаграммы не появляются.
[image: повторный вызов js-кода для диаграмм echarts не срабатывает - диаграмм нет]
Хочу разобраться, какие исправления нужно внести в js-код для echarts, чтобы можно было вызывать его несколько раз для разных вкладок (на одной html-странице).

Comment: Если не здесь, то залейте куда-нибудь Ваш код для самодостаточного примера, т.к. не понятно появляются ли ошибки, что это за библиотека, что за вкладки, присутствуют ли элементы на странице во время вызова кода (т.к. содержимое вкладок может подгружаться динамически вовремя переключения на них)...